# How an own written assembly file must be included in maven project?

Tags: java, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

i have written an own assembly file for my maven project to build a war file by using the maven assembly plugin.

I´m not sure, in which path my assemmbly.xml file must be placed in the maven project? And in which way can I configure that path in the file pom.xml?

This is my assembly file:

```
<assembly
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.0.xsd">

    <id>FirstWarFileTest</id>

    <formats>
        <format>war</format>
    </formats>

</assembly>
```

Here is a snippet of my pom.xml file:

```
 <plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
     <configuration>                    
        <descriptorRef>
            <descriptor>assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
        </descriptorRef>

   .....
  </plugin>
```

After I have insert the command mvn clean install I get this error message:
No assembly describtors found.

Answer (score 0):

The tag descriptorRef is for the [predefined descriptors](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html) apart from that your definition is wrong:

```xml
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    [...]
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <!-- NOTE: We don't need a groupId specification because the group is
             org.apache.maven.plugins ...which is assumed by default.
         -->
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
        [...]
</project>
```

If you are using your own file you have to go via:

```xml
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    [...]
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <descriptors>
            <descriptor>src/assembly/src.xml</descriptor>
          </descriptors>
        </configuration>
        [...]
</project>
```

Comment: thanks ! Could you explain in which folder of the maven project the file "assembly.xml" or "src.xml" muste be placed? In "src/main/resources"?

Comment: Take a look into the given examples `src/assembly/` would be a good location. `src/main/resources` is simply wrong cause they shouldn't be packaged itself.

Comment: is src/assembly a source folder?

Comment: what do you mean by a `a source folder` it just contains the assembly descriptors nothing else.

Comment: Ok, let me say it in another words: Which kind of folder I must created? Is this a normal folder or a source folder in eclipse IDE? And in which folder of the maven project this kind of folder must be placed by myself? Must a created the folder / source folder in src/main/java or in src/main/resources?

Comment: I already wrote `src/assembly`. Create a new filder for this.